# Using Selenium explicit waits in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of IPs that are for ~600 modems that are currently deployed. Some of these modems will be accessible and some will not be due to connectivity or the battery having died. Basically want to loop through all the IPs and do an explicit wait for the bottom text string that contains the modem's firmware version. If the station doesn't load I want it to add 'No Connection' in place of the IP. I'd like to take that firmware append it in an empty list and then print that list into a csv.

My main roadblock seems to be the WebDriverWait(driver,30).until portion of the code seems to always throw an exception even when I've pulled from the same locator previously. I see the browser load and then it will still throw the exception. I've tried several of the 'Standard Expected Conditions' and none of them seem to work.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import os
import csv

prefix = 'http://'
suffix = ':9191'

fwlist = []
iplist = ["###.###.###.###", ...]


class presence_of_element_located(object):
    """ An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM
    of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.
    locator - used to find the element
    returns the WebElement once it is located
    """
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        return _find_element(driver, self.locator)

for ip in iplist:
        url = prefix + ip + suffix
        # instantiate a chrome options object so you can set the size and headless preference
        # some of these chrome options might be uncessary but I just used a boilerplate
        # change the <path_to_download_default_directory> to whatever your default download folder is located
        chrome_options = Options()
        #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--verbose')
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
                "download.default_directory": r"Z:\Python\Scaping\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe",
                "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                "download.directory_upgrade": True,
                "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
                "safebrowsing.enabled": False
        })
        #chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
        # initialize driver object and change the <path_to_chrome_driver> depending on your directory where your chromedriver should be
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"Z:\Python\Scaping\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
        # get request to target the site selenium is active on
        driver.get(f'{url}')
        try:
                WebDriverWait(driver,30,.5).until(presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"login_screen")))
                print(f'{url} is ready')
        except:
                print(f'Timeout for {url}')
                fw = 'No connection'
                fwlist.append(fw)

        text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]").text
        fw = text.split(' ',3)
        fwlist.append(fw[3])
        print(fwlist)
        driver.close()

with open('Scaping\PGE-FW.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(fw)

driver.quit()
```

For testing I use one working and one nonworking IPs, but I see the working one load fine in the 30 seconds but it always makes an exception.

Below is an image of the html with the ID for the wait and the xpath of the data I want. I don't really know a way to provide you all with the html of the modem's internal web page but if anyone has a way please let me know. So i guess I have two questions: Am I making some obvious error why this isn't working or perhaps there is a better way to go about this?

[image]

Comment: Which selenium exception its is throwing ?

Comment: Apologies, should have included that. My understanding is that WebDriverWait will always give a 'NoSuchElementException'.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot an import.

```
Needed:
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

From:
WebDriverWait(driver,30,.5).until(presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"login_screen")))

To:
WebDriverWait(driver,30,.5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"login_screen")))
```